# Guardar localização do usuário

Tags: postgresql, django, modelagem, geolocalização

Estou tentando guardar a localização do usuário em uma base dados, para posteriormente gerar relatórios sobre usuários por país, estado e região.

Inicialmente baixei bases que continham o nome de todas as cidades do mundo, em vários idiomas, mas isso deixou a manutenção da aplicação um horror. Sem dizer que é impraticável manter a base atualizada.

Eu pensei em partir para uso de uma API como a do Google, só que quando os usuários pedem uma localização na API, os resultados vem no idioma do usuário. Então é possível que eu tenha na base Nova York, New York e ainda outras versões, o que complica a geração de relatórios.

Gostaria de uma ajuda para modelar o dado de forma que possa guardar e pesquisar, sem ter que dispor uma lista com todos o nomes do mundo. Estou usando Django/PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Um tema complicado, unica solução que vejo é usar a api do Google para pegar a localização (não importando em qual idioma) e salvar a unica coisa que é comum a qualquer idioma: coordenadas! Então quando o cara digitar Nova York/New York/NY você vai pegar as coordenadas e salvar. O único cuidado a se tomar é verificar se o Google sempre retorna a mesma coordenada para se referir a uma mesma cidade, porém acredito que ele retorne.

Somente uma sugestão, boa sorte!